# Consulta SQL para filtrar por fecha un Datetime sin Incluir la hora

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Tengo una consulta en sql que busca unos XML por rango de fechas, pero creo que no me esta regresando resultados ya que el where es con el datetime y solo le mando la fecha..
Alguna sugerencia ?

```
SELECT A.e_rfc,a.fecha as fecha,C.SupplierName ,A.folio,A.r_usocfdi,A.cantidad,A.clv_prodyserv,A.descripcion,A.clv_unidad,A.valorunitario,A.importe,
    B.fecha_pago,B.forma_pago,B.moneda,B.monto,B.ImpPagado ,B.foliofiscal_rel,B.folio_rel,B.serie_rel,B.metodo_pago,B.num_parcialidad
    FROM cfdigeneral as A, cfdidetalle as B, Proveedores As C
    WHERE A.uuid=B.uuid AND A.e_rfc=C.RFC And A.fecha = @fecha
```

La fecha la mando desde c# ya intente mandando solo la fecha y enviando la fecha en datetime pero con las horas en 00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Castea la fecha a DATE

```
SELECT A.e_rfc,a.fecha as fecha,C.SupplierName ,A.folio,A.r_usocfdi,A.cantidad,A.clv_prodyserv,A.descripcion,A.clv_unidad,A.valorunitario,A.importe,
    B.fecha_pago,B.forma_pago,B.moneda,B.monto,B.ImpPagado ,B.foliofiscal_rel,B.folio_rel,B.serie_rel,B.metodo_pago,B.num_parcialidad
    FROM cfdigeneral as A, cfdidetalle as B, Proveedores As C
    WHERE A.uuid=B.uuid AND A.e_rfc=C.RFC And CAST(A.fecha AS DATE) = @fecha
```

Answer (score 1):

Extrae solo la fecha de lo que llegue de la BD con la funcion `DATE()` y luego lo comparas con el fomato de la fecha que le estas enviando

```
SELECT A.e_rfc,a.fecha as fecha,C.SupplierName ,A.folio,A.r_usocfdi,A.cantidad,A.clv_prodyserv,A.descripcion,A.clv_unidad,A.valorunitario,A.importe,
    B.fecha_pago,B.forma_pago,B.moneda,B.monto,B.ImpPagado ,B.foliofiscal_rel,B.folio_rel,B.serie_rel,B.metodo_pago,B.num_parcialidad
    FROM cfdigeneral as A, cfdidetalle as B, Proveedores As C
    WHERE A.uuid=B.uuid AND A.e_rfc=C.RFC And DATE(A.fecha) = @fecha
                                            //asi ....
```

Te dejo en link donde encotraras mas sobre [Funciones sql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp)

Espero te sirva, Me cuentas

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción que podría ayudarte es la función Convert :

Este link te puede ayudar [Documentación Convert y Cast](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT A.e_rfc,a.fecha as fecha,C.SupplierName ,A.folio,A.r_usocfdi,A.cantidad,A.clv_prodyserv,A.descripcion,A.clv_unidad,A.valorunitario,A.importe,
    B.fecha_pago,B.forma_pago,B.moneda,B.monto,B.ImpPagado ,B.foliofiscal_rel,B.folio_rel,B.serie_rel,B.metodo_pago,B.num_parcialidad
    FROM cfdigeneral as A, cfdidetalle as B, Proveedores As C
    WHERE A.uuid=B.uuid AND A.e_rfc=C.RFC And Convert(DATE,A.fecha) = @fecha
```